# How to parse 何てこった

Tags: contractions

Is 何てこった a contraction of なんてこう行った, or なんてこう言った, or is this something totally different?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It comes from

> なんてことだ

([source](https://www.weblio.jp/content/%E4%BD%95%E3%81%A6%E3%81%93%E3%81%A3%E3%81%9F))

As the result of a sound change.

It is colloquial.